# Dev Studio 2013 upgrade reports a Web Deployment Project as incompatible

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-deployment-project

I have been given the task to port an dev studio 2010 asp.net solution over to 2013. The only remaining problem I have are we seem to have 2 web deployment projects (i.e. they have a .wdproj extension), and dev studio 2013 reports them as "incompatible", and then when you expand the node, the extra error description "The application is not installed" (see screen shot below)....

[image]

I have done a lot of searching and can just not find a clear answer (they just seem to explain what these projects are etc)

So, my question is
* Are these project supported in dev studio 2013, and if so is there some other plugin I need to install.
* If they are NOT supported, is there an equivalent I need to use, and is there a way to convert from one to the other.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Peter

Answer (score 2):

These are no longer supported in VS2013 (or [even in VS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/06/plans-regarding-website-projects-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx) for that matter).  Almost all of the features have been rolled up into the publish features build in to the product, without the need for a separate project.

See http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2012/visual-studio-2012-web-publishing-improvements for a walkthrough of how publishing works in the newer versions.

Comment: You can, however, use the [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx) which I can confirm works.